# Como selecionar ultimo registro da tabela MySQL com last ou outro comando?

Tags: mysql

Como selecionar ultimo registro da tabela MySQL com `last` ou **outro comando**

Por exemplo:

```
select last registro from tabela where coluna = 23;
```

Já tentei com este código mas não funcionou.

Comment: Qual é nessa tabela o item que faz auto-incremento?

Answer (score 4):

Se a tabela possuir um campo *auto incremento* faça a ordenação *decrescente* e limite o resultado em **1** linha.

```
SELECT registro FROM tabela WHERE coluna = 23 ORDER BY id DESC limit 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Já faz muito tempo essa pergunta, mas segue a resposta.

```
SELECT MAX(id) as maxId FROM table
```

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT MAX(id) as maxId FROM table
```

Acho que este tipo de consulta traz o maior valor e não o último!

Comment: Sim, está correto. Mas essa é a ideia, em uma tabela com o campo `id`(auto_increment), por mais que sofra exclusões de registros,  sempre vai pegar o maior valor da coluna `id`(auto_increment)